# What is the right color of calcium copper titanate?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, color

I'm browsing Alibaba for calcium copper titanium oxide $\ce{CaCu3Ti4O12}$ (CCTO) and I find it variety of colors: pure brown, pale brown, reddish brown or grayish dark brown. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcium_copper_titanate) does not tell the right color either.

What is the right color for CCTO?

All of these below are sold as CCTO on Alibaba. Can it be that they have different color but are equally valid products?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check the MSDS of calcium copper titanate: https://www.ltschem.com/msds/CaCu3Ti4O12.pdf

Comment: @NilayGhosh Thank you. Although this card does not answer my answer I still find a valuable source of information for this compound. Yet, if it say brown without any other remarks then I suspect that the first example is the closest to expected.